# MvvmCross. It is not possible to add a custom dll reference to MvvmCross.Core library project

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to add a DLL to my MvvmCross.core library project. However the included namespaces cannot be resolved for some reason, when I'm trying to refer the namespaces from one of the ViewModels. In object viewer I can see the included namespaces.

When I refer the same DLL from MvvmCross.Droid project I do not see the problem.

Unfortunate I do not have the source code so I need to refer it as a DLL.

I have tried this both on VS2013 and Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 2):

Is your `MvvmCross.core` project a portable class library?  If it is you won't be able to reference it.

What you can do is create another platform specific project, `MyThing.Droid`, and reference the .DLL.  In the `MvvmCross.core` project, create an interface, `IMyThingService`. In `MyThing.Droid` create, `MyThingService` that implements `IMyThingService` and does the stuff you want.  Now you can get a reference to `IMyThingService` and call `DoStuff()` from the `MvvmCross.core` project.

You can also use the plugin model provided by `MvvmCross` to accomplish this.

```
public class MyThingService : IMyThingService
    {
        public void DoStuff()
        {
        }
    }

    public interface IMyThingService
    {
        void DoStuff();
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is a PCL. I will try Your solution. Thanks